# Problems using Visual Studio through Anaconda

Tags: python, import, anaconda

While Anaconda is nice, my experience trying to use Visual Studio through Anaconda is a mess. I have just ended up using Spyder which is great but I'd preferably use visual studio.

Couple of issues:

I select base conda interpreter in visual studio and proceed to try to import pandas or numpy. This results in an error (AttributeError: module 'tokenize' has no attribute 'Name').

A couple of days ago it randomly worked and now it's not. running print('hello') works just fine.

I have no issues with any imports in Spyder but I've started using Flask and it'd be much easier to have it all in one workspace.

Any understanding why I cannot import pandas.

Edit: Did a clean reinstall of both and now am able to install numpy. However, I get the error when trying to install pandas. Using 3.8.3. Pandas works in Spyder, not in VS Code.

Comment: What error do you get while installing Pandas. Try to check if there is a conflict of environment variables of "Anaconda Python" and ordinary Python installation

Comment: @SuyashKumar I don't get an error. It is already installed. I tried a couple other errors. I also got a tokenize error when i tried to import matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: I was able to create a new virtual environment and import without issues there. Any idea why it doesn't work on the base environment.

Comment: Does it work on the anaconda prompt. This thing once happened to me also as I had messed up my path variables and there was a clash between my original one and anaconda.

Comment: No problems there. ```pip install pandas``` just returns requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Be careful! Don't use the base environment for development, and installing pip packages there will further increase the risk that something will break.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it started working for no apparent reason. I just restarted VS Code through Anaconda and this time it had no issues. As I said, I feel like VS Code is all over the place through Anaconda and not very reliable.

Comment: Nice that it is working, it will be better if you use a clean python installation for working with Flask